# Angularjs : update a displayed image src

Tags: angularjs

I have an image display on my view like this :

```
<img  ng-src="api/downloadFile/{{vm.consultant.id}}/lien_avatar" width="120" height="120">
```

Now I would like to make this image clickable with the possibility to choose another picture and then reload the displayed image.

How can I achieve that?
I have tried to use `$resource(api/downloadFile/vm.consultant.id/lien_avatar)` in the controller but no image is displayed.

**[UPDATE]** 
[image]

**[UPDATE2]**

When I load the view, if I have :

```
<img  ng-src="api/downloadFile/{{vm.consultant.id}}/lien_avatar" width="120" height="120">
```

It works, but I can't update the image. When I inspect ng-src  I am getting `api/downloadFile/58/lien_avatar`

If I change to  :

```
<img  ng-src="{{imageUR}}" width="120" height="120">
```

and in controller :

```
$http.get('api/downloadFile/' + vm.consultant.id + '/lien_avatar').then(function(response){
                 vm.imageURL  = response.data;
            });
```

Then when I inspect ng-src after the view is loaded I am getting the posted image in previous [UPDATE] section.

Comment: what does `api/downloadFile/{{vm.consultant.id}}/lien_avatar` return?

Comment: may I know why you are using `{{}}` inside javascript?

Comment: Please also post the API controller code to show what is returned to the client.

Comment: Probably you are receiving the image in base64 so add `'data:image/png;base64,'` before the data. `vm.imageURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + response.data`

Comment: apparently that's not it. I have tried base64